# when printing a char* in C only the first character is being printed

Tags: c, substring, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

I'm trying to write a function that will print out a substring of string however when printing it, only the first character in the array is printed.

As you can see in the code I've put a `printf` statement in the function after the substring is created and it displays properly.  However when the function is passed into a `printf` function in the main function it only prints the first character.

Thanks for any help people are able to provide.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *ft_substr (const char *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)
{
    char        *str;
    unsigned int    i;
    unsigned int    j;

    str = malloc(len * sizeof(char) + 1);
    i = start;
    j = 0;
    while (i < len + start)
    {
        str[j] = s[i];
        j++;
        i++;
    }
    str[j + 1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    free(str);
    return (str);
}

int main (void)
{
    char hello[] = "Hello World";
    char sub = *ft_substr(hello, 1, 4);

    printf("%s\n", &sub);
    return (0);

}
```

Comment: `free(str); return (str);` Returning freed memory is not going to end well. Remove the `free` and leave it to the caller to do that.

Comment: `char sub;`  should be `char *sub;` and `printf("%s\n", &sub);` should be `printf("%s\n", sub);` that is `char *sub = ft_substr(hello, 1, 4); printf("%s\n", sub);`

Comment: thanks for the advice regarding the freed memory.

Comment: I tried adding * to sub but I got the error warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'char'; remove * [-Wint-conversion]
        char *sub = *ft_substr(hello, 1, 4);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before returning the pointer `str` from the function you freed all the allocated memory

```
free(str);
return (str);
```

So the returned pointer is invalid.

Remove the statement

```
free(str);
```

Another problem in the function is using an incorrect index in this statement

```
str[j + 1] = '\0';
```

Just write

```
str[j] = '\0';
```

Also this declaration is incorrect

```
char sub = *ft_substr(hello, 1, 4);
```

It declares a single character while you need to declare a pointer that will point to the dynamically allocated string in the function. So write

```
char *sub = ft_substr(hello, 1, 4);
```

and then write

```
printf("%s\n", sub);

free( sub );
```

And if you are using the type `size_t` for the length of a string then use indices also of the type `size_t`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * ft_substr( const char *s, size_t start, size_t len )
{
    char *str = malloc( len + 1 );
    
    if ( str != NULL )
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        for ( ; i < len; i++ )
        {
            str[i] = s[start + i];
        }
        
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
    
    return str;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *hello= "Hello World";
    
    char *sub = ft_substr( hello, 1, 4 );

    if ( sub != NULL ) puts( sub );
    
    free( sub );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
ello
```

The function will be more safer if it will check whether the starting index and the length are specified correctly. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * ft_substr( const char *s, size_t start, size_t len )
{
    char *str = NULL;
    
    size_t n = strlen( s );
    
    if ( start < n )
    {
        if ( n - start < len ) len = n - start;
    
        str = malloc( len + 1 );
    
        if ( str )
        {
            memcpy( str, s + start, len );
            str[len] = '\0';
        }
    }
    
    return str;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *hello= "Hello World";
    
    char *sub = ft_substr( hello, 1, 4 );

    if ( sub != NULL ) puts( sub );
    
    free( sub );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have UB in your main. Yout try to print as string a single character (passed as reference).

```
int main (void)
{
    char hello[] = "Hello World";
    char *sub = ft_substr(hello, 1, 4);

    printf("%s\n", sub?sub:"");
    free(sub);
    return (0);

}
```